# SQL: how to understand the solution code without using rank()?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone explain to me why the code would work? the problem is leetcode 178 rank score(https://leetcode.com/problems/rank-scores/)

```
SELECT
  Score,
  (SELECT count(distinct Score) FROM Scores WHERE Score >= s.Score) Rank
FROM Scores s
ORDER BY Score desc
```

My question is about this part: `(SELECT count(distinct Score) FROM Scores WHERE Score >= s.Score) as Rank`

why it would work as ranking like 1,2,3... like enumeration, rather than just count like 4

Comment: Learn how to use `dense_rank()`.  Then . . . when you are really comfortable with SQL, investigate alternative methods for implementing it using correlated subqueries (which you would never use in practice on a modern database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important point is that SQL has a built-in function to do ranking.  That is more important for learning SQL then understanding why this particular code works.

BUT, if you are going to use correlated subqueries, it is *very* important to qualify *all* column references in the query.  So, the query should look like:

```
SELECT s.Score,
       (SELECT count(distinct s2.Score)
        FROM Scores s2
        WHERE s2.Score >= s.Score
--------------^ correlation clause "connects" the subquery to the outer query
       ) as Rank
FROM Scores s
ORDER BY s.Score desc;
```

This code is counting the number of values greater than or equal to a particular score.  That is how the correlation clause works.  The subquery is counting the number of distinct scores greater than or equal to each score in the outer query.  If you don't understand this, you need to learn more about correlated subqueries; start with the documentation for your database.

Note that in SQL parlance, this is the the `dense_rank()`.  And using that function is both simpler and should have much better perofrmance.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow mysql code will work like dense_rank() in mysql-

```
SELECT  IF(score <> @pscore,@i:=@i+1,@i:=@i) AS rank,
  @pscore := score AS score
 FROM scores p ,(SELECT @i := 0,@pscore := 0) r
ORDER BY score desc
```

Comment: Thanks. Could u tell me what is the term for '@' and ':=' in sql server? I'd like to research how to understand and use it